# Update and row id with SQl connector Azure Logic apps

Tags: sql, azure-logic-apps

So i have a little problem here.

The Update sql connector in azure, how do i dynamically update a row by dynamically specifying the row_id.

ROW_ID:
[image: ROWID]

I tried having:

> @string(actions('Converter')['outputs']['body']['Id'])

inside there, from a previous action but it didnt work i get an error.

is there any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to get that to work after some struggling.

The problem seems to be that you can't select dynamic content into the row id column because of some UI bug. By going into code view I would use the same expression as for the Id.

[image]

See example below on how I changed the path.

```
                   "Update_row": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "body": {
                            "Id": "@{item()?['Id']}",
                        },
                        "path": "/datasets/default/tables/Inquiries/items/@{encodeUriComponent(item()?['Id'])}"
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MikaelEliasson .
I'll try it as soon as i get some free time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to LogicApps WDL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language) for the in built functions support.
For this case you can use **@int()**

Convert the parameter to an integer. For example, this function returns 100 as a number, rather than a string:
int('100')
Parameter number: 1
Name: Value
Description: Required. The value that is converted to an integer.

Comment: i tried that, it didnt work, still got the same error:

" Failed to save logic app LA_EM_1. The template validation failed: 'The template action 'Update_row' at line '1' and column '43442' is not valid: "Unable to parse template language expression 'encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('@int(actions('Converter')['outputs']['body']['id'])'))': expected token 'RightParenthesis' and actual 'Identifier'.".'. "