# Azure LogicApp cannot get rowid from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure logicapp that connects to a SQL Server database in Azure. The table has a `uniqueidentifier` column as the primary key. In the logic app the delete or update requires the `rowid` in order to perform update, the primary key does not work here and throws an error when running, stating that the table does not have a primary key. It does, and is additionally confirmed when inserting a row twice in the logicapp it knows about the primary key's constraint, being unique.

If I `Get Rows` and filter by the primary key column, the resulting array lists each item found (the one obviously) but does not make available the rowid as a dynamic expression.

How is one to actually get the rowid? Is it possible to update a row using just the primary key?

UPDATE:

The `uuid` is generated outside of the logicapp and is passed to it as a string.
It should be noted that inserting works just fine.

Here the logicapp requires a rowid specifier, but using the `uuid` fails. I thought I could then instead get all rows filtered by uuid and update them, as a work around, but I could not get the `rowid`. Another person had a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516709/1298523) and could not get the `rowid` without editing the source code; however this method of adding the rowid in the body section of the code no longer seems to work as the result is empty.
[image]
The logicapp error I receive during an `update` or `delete` when using the uuid is:

`{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Execution Failure\r\n     inner exception: The specified table has no primary key. Update and delete operations are not supported.\r\nclientRequestId: 555",
  "source": "sql-555.p.azurewebsites.net"
}`

With that said the `insert` goes fine and the `uuid` I pass get's placed into the table.

Insert result:
[image]

Comment: Put a default value of newid() on the uniqueidentifier column.

Comment: Please post the code and the error message. Your explanation is not specific enough.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I updated my question hopefully it's more specific thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I actually deleted the entire logicapp and rebuilt it and now it recognizes that the uuid column is a PK. I believe when the app is first connected to SQL it stores the schema and never updated afterwards. I had rebuilt the connection a few times but the only thing that got it to update was by rebuilding the logicapp itself. I'm a bit convinced this is a bug, so I'm leaving here as an answer in case anyone ever comes in to this issue in the future

Comment: You can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this reminder. I have definitely experienced this in the past and re-reading this helped me fix my issue... Yep, just start w/ fresh widgets for new schema.

Comment: I didn't have to delete the entire Logic App, just delete the Action, save the Logic App, re-add it. This drove me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rebuilding the logic app from scratch, you could instead press "Refresh" (right next to the "Edit" button when going to edit your logic app). Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column default (like NEWID()) on the primary key, remove it.

Generate the uniqueidentifier directly in your logic app, and just insert it like any other column into the table in Azure SQL DB. If you do that, you already have the GUID value that you can then use later in the same app code.

If that's not the issue, I think you need to give us some code to read so we can help more.

Comment: I updated my question to be more detailed. I generate the uuid outside of the logicapp and inserting works fine. It's the Update or Delete that do not work when using the same uuid, it seems

Answer (score 0):

I'd similar issue, but setting column (for which value is passed in Rowid) as primary key in the database table fixed the update row execution error. Columns to be updated can be added as parameters with the respective values.. Thank you !

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.